# How does the Keras Embedding Layer work if word is not found?

Tags: python, keras

I am using the Keras Embedding Layer for text classification. When I try to predict using the `model.predict` API, how does it work if there is a word that doesn't exist in the training dataset?

I understand that the embedding layer is a table lookup. So if the key(the word in the test sample) is not found how does it deal with it?

Edit: This is how I preprocess the data to predict

```
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(['this is random car text'])
data = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
model.predict(np.array(data))
```

The pretrained model has also pickled the tokenizer object so that encoding the text during testing results in same encoding numbers for words that exist in the training corpus.

Comment: You're better off thinking of it as a matrix multiplication, if the test word doesn't exist in the training data and you haven't used any transfer learning of the embedding layer the output would be random.

Comment: This is assuming I've understood you properly and you don't mean that the word is out of range of the input dimension (the size of the vocabulary) in which case I'm 99% certain some exception will be raised

Comment: No, I mean its out of range of the input vocabulary. I am using a pretrained model on which I am predicting. So there may be proper nouns and other words not included in the training dataset. There is no exception being raised, or any error for that matter.

Comment: What you're saying is strange, include code please, I need to see how you're preparing the data for the embedding (input) layer

Comment: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7551

Comment: Personally I tend to a more hands on approach to my data preparation, it tends to improve crucial understanding of what goes on under the hood of ML quite a lot