# Making predictions on text data using keras

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, prediction, sentiment-analysis

i had trained and tested a CNN for sentiment analysis. The train and test data were prepared the same way, tokenizing the sentence and giving unique integers:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(filters='$%&()*/:;<=>@[\\]^`{|}~\t\n')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(text)
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(text)
```

Then pre-trained glove model to create embedding matrix for CNN as:

```
filepath_glove = 'glove.twitter.27B.200d.txt'
glove_vocab = []
glove_embd=[]
embedding_dict = {}

file = open(filepath_glove,'r',encoding='UTF-8')
for line in file.readlines():
    row = line.strip().split(' ')
    vocab_word = row[0]
    glove_vocab.append(vocab_word)
    embed_vector = [float(i) for i in row[1:]] # convert to list of float
    embedding_dict[vocab_word]=embed_vector
   file.close()
  for word, index in tokenizer.word_index.items(): 
 `embedding_matrix[index] = embedding_dict[word]`
```

At this point i also used the test sentences to create this matrix which was later passed as weights into embedding layer:

```
e= Embedding(vocab_size, 200, input_length=maxSeqLength, weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False)(inp)
```

Now i want to reload my model and test with some new data but it would mean that embedding matrix wont include some words from new data.This makes me wonder that if even before i shouldnt have had included test data while creating embedding matrix? And if not,how does the embedding layer work for those new words?This part is similar to this question but i couldnt find answer: 
[How does the Keras Embedding Layer work if word is not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474477/how-does-the-keras-embedding-layer-work-if-word-is-not-found)
Thanks

Comment: Could you please concentrate on one question and provide [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Edited.I hope its clear now

Answer (score 0):

It´s quite simple. You are providing the vocab_size, which is the number of words, the embedding layer knows. If you pass an index, which is out of bounds of the vocab_size (new word), it will be ignored, or an error will be thrown by keras.

This answers your question regarding if you should include all data for your embedding matrix. Yes, you should.

Comment: Thanks alot..but the thing is that whats the point of having a trained model if you need to change the embedding matrix for every new data.Ideally i know that it already should include the words that you expect to have in your test data but some words are always new. Keras text to sequences just skips the new words but i am also using POS tags so i dont want to mess with the length of the sentence.Is there a way to tell text to sequence to use a special integer for all the new words so atleast sentence length remains same?

Comment: Its common practice to train your embeddings on a huge dataset, like wikipedia and then reuse the embedding for your task. You can use pretrained Glove, word2vec or fastText embeddings for example. Or you can use subword embeddings.

Comment: i am using Glove trained on tweets  but the question is not that what if those words are not found pre trained GloVe model. My problem is that i used it to create embedding matrix from training set. What if the test data contains some new words as you mentioned in your first comment? How should i deal with that?Thanks

Comment: I don´t know if I understood correctly. You are using only those glove embeddings, which occured in the training set in the test case? Then the solution is just to use all glove embeddings in your embedding matrix, not only the onces occured in the training phase.

Comment: Yes,i am constructing embedding matrix with the words in training set..thats how it usually happens i think . I have added the code. I guess the solution is to either add embeddings for all the words in new test data as well or use some specific index for all unknown words.